# VS code type inference working better than Typescript?

Tags: typescript, types, visual-studio-code

Referencing - https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/30175

and

https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=interface%20User%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20editorParams%3F%3A%20SelectParams%20%7C%20AutoCompleteParams%3B%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Alet%20user%3A%20User%3B%0D%0A%0D%0Alet%20autoComplete1%3A%20AutoCompleteParams%20%3D%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20searchFunc%3A%20(term%2C%20values)%20%3D%3E%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%2F%2Fsearch%20for%20exact%20matches%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20var%20matches%3A%20string%5B%5D%20%3D%20%5B%5D%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%2F%2Freturn%20matches%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20listItemFormatter%3A%20function(value%2C%20title)%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%2F%2Fprefix%20all%20titles%20with%20the%20work%20%22Mr%22%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20return%20%22Mr%20%22%20%2B%20title%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%2C%0D%0A%20%20%7D%3B%0D%0A%20%20user.editorParams%20%3D%20autoComplete1%3B%0D%0A%20%20%0D%0A%20%20user.editorParams%20%3D%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20searchFunc%3A%20(term%2Cvalues)%20%3D%3E%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%2F%2Fsearch%20for%20exact%20matches%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20var%20matches%3A%20string%5B%5D%20%3D%20%5B%5D%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%2F%2Freturn%20matches%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20listItemFormatter%3A%20function(value%2C%20title)%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%2F%2Fprefix%20all%20titles%20with%20the%20work%20%22Mr%22%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20return%20%22Mr%20%22%20%2B%20title%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%2C%0D%0A%20%20%7D%3B%0D%0A%0D%0A%20%20interface%20SelectParams%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20listItemFormatter%3F%3A%20(value%3A%20string%2C%20text%3A%20string)%20%3D%3E%20string%3B%0D%0A%20%20%7D%0D%0A%0D%0A%20%20interface%20AutoCompleteParams%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20listItemFormatter%3F%3A%20(value%3A%20string%2C%20text%3A%20string)%20%3D%3E%20string%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20searchFunc%3A%20(term%3A%20string%2C%20values%3A%20string%5B%5D)%20%3D%3E%20string%5B%5D%3B%0D%0A%20%20%7D

Does anyone have an idea why VS code can infer the right type on line 21 but the TypeScript compiler does not and I expect it to produce the same error as line 8.

Answer (score 0):

Possibly VSCode is linting the entire file, whereas the compiler runs until the first error, then stops?